# Drag and Drop email from Outlook causes exception in mso20win32client.dll

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop, com-interop, mapi

Seems around early August some users on several different RDS servers cannot drag and drop from Outlook to our app (Launcher.exe).  Any thoughts on what may be causing this?  Seems consistent for users with the problem but other users on same server can do this ok.

I tried everything short of repair office or recreate windows profile.  I'd like to avoid that if I can.

- selected show all pictures on email before drag and drop from outlook
- dragged msg file to cloud file system, dragged to Launcher
  -- this showed message added to queue but then crashes Launcher. also crashes Launcheron startup. event viewer shows missing key field shown below
- sent html email to inbox that contains only text. dragged email from inbox to Launcher
- sent plain text email to inbox. dragged from inbox to Launcher
- Tried removing the ost file and restarted outlook
- Drag and drop to file system works ok
- Created new profile in outlook using user's exchange account
- Created new folder under inbox and copied email to it for testing

Looking at a proc mon trace seems we're using outlook interop in GAC and redemption.dll.

```
Description:
Faulting application name: Launcher.exe, version: 22.1.4.16, time stamp: 0x62d88eb6
Faulting module name: mso20win32client.dll, version: 16.0.4513.1000, time stamp: 0x62e27d99
Exception code: 0x023476c3
Fault offset: 0x001ce29e
Faulting process id: 0x5d50
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8b314eaa1c079
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Launcher\Launcher.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
Report Id: 2cde9333-0d5b-4f8c-b1bb-2d7cabf0ffc5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 



get-item 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll'|fl *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16
PSChildName       : mso20win32client.dll
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
                    InternalName:     Mso20Win32Client
                    OriginalFilename: Mso20Win32Client.dll
                    FileVersion:      16.0.4513.1000
                    FileDescription:  Microsoft Office 2016 component
                    Product:          Microsoft Office 2016
                    ProductVersion:   16.0.4513.1000
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:         English (United States)
                    
BaseName          : mso20win32client
Target            : {}
LinkType          : 
Name              : mso20win32client.dll
Length            : 1922816
DirectoryName     : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16
Directory         : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
Extension         : .dll
CreationTime      : 3/7/2017 6:59:52 AM
CreationTimeUtc   : 3/7/2017 12:59:52 PM
LastAccessTime    : 1/14/2019 3:51:27 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/14/2019 9:51:27 PM
LastWriteTime     : 3/7/2017 6:59:52 AM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 3/7/2017 12:59:52 PM
Attributes        : Archive
```

```
CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=fd619c01 ebx=00000505 ecx=023476c3 edx=028bf958 esi=00000000 edi=0ae59434
eip=6325e29e esp=028bf95c ebp=028bf990 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210246
mso20win32client+0x1ce29e:
6325e29e c7050000000001000000 mov dword ptr ds:[0],1  ds:002b:00000000=????????
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 6325e29e (mso20win32client+0x001ce29e)
   ExceptionCode: 023476c3
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 00000000

PROCESS_NAME:  Launcher.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x23476c3 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  23476c3

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

IP_ON_HEAP:  632c68e9
The fault address in not in any loaded module, please check your build's rebase
log at <releasedir>\bin\build_logs\timebuild\ntrebase.log for module which may
contain the address if it were loaded.

FRAME_ONE_INVALID: 1

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
028bf990 632c68e9     023476c3 00000000 028bfa30 mso20win32client+0x1ce29e
028bf9c4 6311eb9c     028bf9e4 028bf9e8 6311eb54 0x632c68e9
028bf9d0 6311eb54     028bf9e4 00000000 0ae59458 mso20win32client+0x8eb9c
028bf9e8 6311eb1f     ffea660f 028bfa94 0ae59878 mso20win32client+0x8eb54
028bfa18 6311eac7     ffea6653 028bfa94 0ae59878 mso20win32client+0x8eb1f
028bfa44 6311ea71     0ae59518 6311ea3f ffea666b mso20win32client+0x8eac7
028bfa7c 6311e9d4     ffea66bf 63568010 0ae59878 mso20win32client+0x8ea71
028bfaa8 6311e975     ffea66df 028bfbb8 028bfaf0 mso20win32client+0x8e9d4
028bfac8 6311e90a     63568010 028bfbb8 6356c59c mso20win32client+0x8e975
028bfae4 6310465c     63568014 63568010 028bfb20 mso20win32client+0x8e90a
028bfaf4 630a0377     00000003 630a00a4 ffea6737 mso20win32client+0x7465c
028bfb20 630a6687     028bfb38 6260ba1c 028bfbb8 mso20win32client+0x10377
028bfb28 6260ba1c     028bfbb8 00000003 028bfb48 mso20win32client+0x16687
028bfb38 61a860a4     028bfbb8 00000003 028bfb7c mso30win32client+0xba1c
028bfb48 61112800     028bfbb8 00000003 429010f3 mso40uiwin32client+0x60a4
028bfb7c 5fdcb300     028bfbb8 00000003 00000003 mso50win32client+0x2800
028bfb90 5e47ff75     028bfbb8 00000003 0ae661ac mso98win32client+0xb300
028bfbe8 5e9a3a62     00000000 57b80000 0aba7cc0 MSO+0xff75
028bfc0c 580b9246     00000000 57b80000 0ae661ac MSO+0x533a62
028bfcd0 57da3097     000013cc 09f5af8c e9345d44 OLMAPI32!HrUnregisterEDPSessionEvents+0x44193
028bfd18 580b9024     e9345d30 580b8f44 580b8f44 OLMAPI32!GetMsmapiRefTrackModuleGroup+0x8870c
028bfd6c 772762c4     00e3f5e4 772762a0 9bb678a8 OLMAPI32!HrUnregisterEDPSessionEvents+0x43f71
028bfd80 77a01b69     0ae3f5e4 23080cce 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
028bfdc8 77a01b34     ffffffff 77a23419 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
028bfdd8 00000000     00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


SYMBOL_NAME:  mso20win32client+1ce29e

MODULE_NAME: mso20win32client

IMAGE_NAME:  mso20win32client.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  ~21s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_23476c3_mso20win32client.dll!Unknown

OS_VERSION:  10.0.14393.5125

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  16.0.4513.1000

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {fc9ab862-eedb-f322-6810-373fb11e1408}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Comment: What does your app do with Outlook or Extended MAPI?

Comment: Drag and drop from outlook to add msg as an attachment into database.  Database trace shows no activity for the user so I think the problem is trying to process the msg in the client app.  I usually see a .tmp file get saved temporarily to a temp folder, that doesn't happen here either.

Comment: But do you open the MSG file? If you treat MSG file as a regular attachment, mso20Win32Client.dll wouldn't even be loaded in your address space.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker found that deleting this key and trying the drag and drop again resolved the problem.  Didn't need to restart either application.  Deleted the key with both applications running.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\Ecs\msomapi
```

Comment: I am still curious what your code did with the MSG file to load mso20Win32Client.dll in your process...